# What is the idiomatic way regarding AngularJS directives to indicate missing attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a custom component in my application:

```
<my-date model="user" field="deletionTime"
            field-value="{{user.deletionTime}}" label="Deletion time" readonly="true"></my-date>
```

Handling optional attributes like **label** is straightforward but what should I do if the user does not supply the `field` attribute?

My first idea is to do something like this:

```
throw { 
    name:        "Directive parameter error", 
    message:     "A mandatory parameter for directive myDate is missing(field)."
};
```

Is this the best practice in the angular world or there is a more idiomatic solution?

Comment: you can have another directive for errors perhaps and route with ng-show to display the appropriate error  as a pop up on screen.

Comment: can you post the code for the directive? at least the `scope` object?

Comment: "Whomever downvoted: care to comment?

Comment: @omouse The question explains everything. My code is irrelevant in this matter.

Comment: @AdamArold the code does matter since your example is using attributes and those affect the scope. The idiomatic solution, whatever it may be, would also consist of *code*. I feel like this question is more suited to [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think throwing an error right away is the best thing to do.  Fail fast with a good descriptive message -- there is no point in pretending everything is ok.  I am not aware of any specific "standard" way of doing it, so your "throw" is as good as any.